# Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '.data'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I ran into this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '.data' imported from **C:\Users\aushe\OneDrive\Documents\7_Semester\KANDEL\KandelReact\backend\seeder.js**
```

[image: On this picture you can see the Terminal Error and the Full Log]

In the seeder script I call:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import colors from 'colors'
import users from '.data/users.js'
import products from './data/products.js'
import User from './models/userModel.js'
import Product from './models/productModel.js'
import Order from './models/orderModel.js'
import connectDB from './config/db.js'
```

I also checked for typos and found none in:

```
'.data/users.js'
'./data/products.js'
```

maybe I am missing a package? Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it was indeed a typo.

I forgot to put a `/` in from of `data/users.js`

This is how it should look like, this is common knowledge though

```
import users from './data/users.js'
import products from './data/products.js'
```